# Calculating multiple functions on multiple collapsed data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, function

I'm fairly new to R and have been trying to get my head around the more elegant ways to use the many vector based functions available. Many of the other answers offer part of a solution but I can't seem to get a combination to work. Some guidance would be nice.

I have a dataframe of stock trading results with multiple columns, i've only shown two here:

```
structure(list(Trade.Profit.Loss.Perc = c(4.25, 0.32, 3.57, -14.06, 
-11.68, 0, 3.03, -22.76, 19.25, 0, 7.2, 1.56, 4.1, -2.27, -9.68, 
7.14, 1.41, -4.96, -7.95, 17.59, -9.09, 4.41, -4.92, -3.75, -13.58, 
-2.44, -3.79, -6.08, -6.63, 7.06, 74.29, -7.64, 45.53, -11.42, 
13.6, -6.47, 18.77, 20.69, -9.67, -4.64, 93.88, 11.96, 0, 3.33, 
-18.27, 0, -8.5, 7.92, 50.86, 10, 24.39, -9.68, -3.91, -14.6, 
3.03, -13.43, -2.09, -0.5, 16.67, 14.52, 0.62, 6, -7.28, -0.47, 
-4.01, 17.4, 12.41, 24.63, 4.71, -15.02, -1.68, 41.13, 0.33, 
0, -6.49, 8.51, -4.29, -2.28, 7.51, 32.27, -9.7, 151.57, 2.31, 
0.48, 31.49, 2.46, 6.61, -0.22, 11.19, -7.63, -4.56, 2.48, -0.62, 
-6.25, 50, -3.2, 27.33, -6.25, 36.03, 29, 11.69, -2.34, -3.77, 
-1.45, -9.76, -5.68, 17.62, -2.7, -1.6, 42.36, -5.41, 0, 7.69, 
15.6, -2.6, -9.4, -4.75, 5.36, 1.07, 24.32, 14.58, 3.64, -29.17, 
-8.27, 8.68, -11.56, -3.57, -2.4, -1.36, -16.98, 3.75, -4.2, 
-8.62, -6.19, -6.31, -11.38, -4.65, 35.74, -6.59, -3.5, -12.53, 
18.18, 1.77, -8.14, -1.75, -0.75, 5.56, 58.54, -6.19, -7.31, 
4.39, 3.25, 2.52, -2.33, -5.3, 27.09, -1.11, -37.14, -7.26, -1.02, 
0, -3.14, 6.56, -7.81, -13.04, 22.38, -1.36, -1.2, -7.49, -9.09, 
11.68, -8.46, -4.42, -1.54, -2.32, 1.2, 0, 4.65, -5.75, -2.5, 
11.74, 7.52, 12.37, 1.22, 14.18, -10.47, 20.63, -6.28, -0.01, 
16.67, 3.12, 5.9, 9.96, 3.45, 38.64, -1.98, 0.71, 6.1, 29.41), 
    Entry.ATRVE = c(2.022, 2.031, 3.979, 3.478, 2.75, 1.784, 
    1.971, 2.904, 1.69, 1.268, 2.624, 1.37, 2.531, 3.379, 1.871, 
    1.989, 3.235, 1.26, 2.423, 0.907, 2.406, 3.459, 1.328, 2.885, 
    3.803, 3.506, 1.738, 2.245, 2.279, 3.661, 2.256, 1.633, 1.777, 
    3.558, 2.336, 1.746, 1.896, 3.075, 3.812, 2.489, 3.372, 3.295, 
    2.022, 1.215, 2.007, 2.644, 3.605, 1.576, 2.596, 3.212, 1.4, 
    3.031, 2.916, 2.254, 2.19, 3.661, 2.046, 2.537, 3.246, 2.091, 
    2.762, 2.742, 1.345, 1.91, 1.293, 1.348, 2.842, 2, 2.672, 
    1.779, 2.068, 3.433, 3.006, 3.525, 3.575, 3.36, 2.168, 1.688, 
    2.567, 0.835, 1.652, 1.422, 3.11, 2.454, 2.27, 1.199, 2.571, 
    1.85, 3.092, 1.932, 1.397, 1.859, 3.141, 2.821, 3.549, 1.594, 
    1.941, 2.526, 2.274, 1.723, 2.058, 3.126, 2.941, 1.953, 2.55, 
    1.909, 2.715, 2.394, 3.152, 2.691, 2.063, 3.163, 1.034, 1.059, 
    0.362, 1.979, 2.075, 1.087, 0.893, 1.56, 2.121, 3.507, 2.813, 
    2.56, 1.459, 2.314, 3.137, 1.798, 2.551, 3.36, 1.41, 1.083, 
    2.641, 2.703, 3.341, 3.831, 2.336, 2.856, 1.906, 2.14, 3.138, 
    1.047, 2.043, 2.467, 1.328, 1.092, 1.821, 1.972, 3.94, 2.412, 
    2.314, 1.668, 0.626, 1.862, 3.442, 2.479, 2.598, 3.307, 1.433, 
    3.45, 3.47, 3.082, 1.978, 2.764, 3.775, 1.908, 2.695, 2.571, 
    1.934, 3.324, 2.411, 1.573, 2.579, 2.34, 3.684, 2.008, 3.225, 
    1.435, 3.283, 1.993, 1.754, 1.063, 1.208, 1.903, 1.312, 2.875, 
    2.676, 2.426, 0.997, 2.654, 1.323, 1.717, 2.547, 1.346, 2.055, 
    1.551, 2.215, 1.396, 3.314), X = c(0.177371087, 0.906809191, 
    0.208469544, 0.151138531, 0.345978372, 0.574636442, 0.385996104, 
    0.861229906, 0.141104879, 0.561812589, 0.340836813, 0.756585548, 
    0.058332616, 0.349425684, 0.932898281, 0.004165203, 0.41053952, 
    0.077378432, 0.058095648, 0.497867816, 0.216763889, 0.571999138, 
    0.800967707, 0.147823619, 0.568139526, 0.952335278, 0.414131303, 
    0.930967507, 0.951035818, 0.655865856, 0.363502228, 0.319418729, 
    0.803576908, 0.302248103, 0.374374328, 0.306277968, 0.562535965, 
    0.45865619, 0.528323919, 0.228827088, 0.090731023, 0.810054676, 
    0.040312554, 0.936651623, 0.613018811, 0.323526959, 0.938253046, 
    0.59613313, 0.096626581, 0.295683059, 0.691093101, 0.370450864, 
    0.953446954, 0.002676696, 0.036867464, 0.304420348, 0.108535358, 
    0.642157095, 0.683799239, 0.751778295, 0.394137427, 0.888028432, 
    0.008651793, 0.41384267, 0.004815106, 0.25080828, 0.022183931, 
    0.598519722, 0.867941507, 0.987371256, 0.56446045, 0.0576671, 
    0.32560138, 0.835096526, 0.585997663, 0.028029888, 0.982674378, 
    0.135163749, 0.717039075, 0.764402586, 0.648966357, 0.48131708, 
    0.364586775, 0.664295882, 0.594879264, 0.131346724, 0.153489409, 
    0.396639421, 0.240334462, 0.970626753, 0.872674761, 0.965853941, 
    0.018889313, 0.500850411, 0.020251346, 0.477868178, 0.441027497, 
    0.464538719, 0.650548595, 0.113164376, 0.953159401, 0.828417591, 
    0.909501277, 0.974955387, 0.005544144, 0.796553436, 0.82135113, 
    0.196713654, 0.161114125, 0.040137343, 0.60080166, 0.731497271, 
    0.484325649, 0.195530412, 0.133857393, 0.052481523, 0.52277393, 
    0.258780518, 0.305323357, 0.609780934, 0.873767561, 0.897915264, 
    0.803924978, 0.844458949, 0.551162924, 0.707426453, 0.756850677, 
    0.782465398, 0.034789665, 0.722527887, 0.430711179, 0.312993878, 
    0.04175475, 0.661157221, 0.377607192, 0.293913794, 0.208493996, 
    0.58177576, 0.828698155, 0.057039434, 0.211224526, 0.269573861, 
    0.169065249, 0.672225791, 0.673528094, 0.258476807, 0.027798473, 
    0.739185813, 0.77504509, 0.76611552, 0.60618332, 0.215831874, 
    0.660387201, 0.529556218, 0.948005457, 0.99885867, 0.774597927, 
    0.885260589, 0.947632843, 0.624328215, 0.253942724, 0.721110859, 
    0.74616445, 0.042866232, 0.166422973, 0.473853092, 0.411103767, 
    0.284882459, 0.672563947, 0.367742347, 0.947790843, 0.981166871, 
    0.646502822, 0.130204379, 0.069492267, 0.115210676, 0.126707369, 
    0.247698717, 0.757196762, 0.607707261, 0.621710909, 0.859949287, 
    0.437920926, 0.245296529, 0.645008787, 0.564204912, 0.800645722, 
    0.767176007, 0.874495379, 0.037927782, 0.595771062, 0.073163803, 
    0.518055909, 0.765729075, 0.646506897, 0.077860654, 0.990334821, 
    0.220478109, 0.196541822), profitable = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 1, 1, 1), ATRVE.cut = structure(c(3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 
    2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
    3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
    3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("[0,1)", 
    "[1,2)", "[2,3)", "[3,4)", "[4,5)", "[5,6)", "[6,7)", "[7,8)", 
    "[8,9)", "[9,32)"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Trade.Profit.Loss.Perc", 
"Entry.ATRVE", "X", "profitable", "ATRVE.cut"), row.names = c(NA, 
-199L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to apply multiple functions to this dataframe after collapsing it and also apply the same functions to subsets of this dataframe; specifically the profit trades and loss trades. So far i have taken the brute force approach with much repetition:

```
Trades = read.csv("Trades.csv")

#Bin the data according the breaks.
breaks = seq(0,9,by=1)
breaks = c(breaks,32)

#Break Trades into Profits and Losses
logP = Trades$Trade.Profit.Loss.Perc >= 0
Profits = Trades[logP,]
logL = Trades$Trade.Profit.Loss.Perc < 0
Losses = Trades[logL,]

#Collapse the dataframes by the ATRVE bins.
T_ATRVE.cut = cut(Trades$Entry.ATRVE, breaks, right=FALSE)
P_ATRVE.cut = cut(Profits$Entry.ATRVE, breaks, right=FALSE)
L_ATRVE.cut = cut(Losses$Entry.ATRVE, breaks, right=FALSE)

#Using Trades, on the specified column vector, use a bin list to calculate each bin statistic.
#Number of Trades
Trade_Num <- with (Trades, tapply(Trades$Trade.Profit.Loss.Perc,list(T_ATRVE.cut),length))
Profits_Num <- with (Profits, tapply(Profits$Trade.Profit.Loss.Perc,list(P_ATRVE.cut),length))
Losses_Num <- with (Losses, tapply(Losses$Trade.Profit.Loss.Perc,list(L_ATRVE.cut),length))


# Mean Return
Trades_Mean <- with (Trades, tapply(Trades$Trade.Profit.Loss.Perc,list(T_ATRVE.cut),mean))
Profits_Mean <- with (Profits, tapply(Profits$Trade.Profit.Loss.Perc,list(P_ATRVE.cut),mean))
Losses_Mean <- with (Losses, tapply(Losses$Trade.Profit.Loss.Perc,list(L_ATRVE.cut),mean))

#Combine the results into one table.
Results = cbind(Trade_Num, Profits_Num, Losses_Num, Trades_Mean, Profits_Mean, Losses_Mean)
```

I have looked at different questions using the [plyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510390/collapse-data-frame-by-group-using-different-functions-on-each-variable) package as well as permutations of the lapply function with [vector lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791760/apply-a-function-to-each-data-frame) and functions but can't make them work. I see the components but can't glue them together!
.......

After applying the condensed code from Ramnath i get the following output:

```
 profitable ATRVE.cut Num      Mean
1          0     [0,1)   2 -1.305000
2          0     [1,2)  30 -5.135667
3          0     [2,3)  40 -6.994250
4          0     [3,4)  27 -8.513333
5          1     [0,1)   4 13.362500
6          1     [1,2)  39 15.673846
7          1     [2,3)  36 15.483056
8          1     [3,4)  21 15.055714
```

I'd like the output to look something like this, with or without extra columns:

```
 profitable ATRVE.cut Num    Mean Profitable Num  Mean
1          0     [0,1)   2 -1.305000  1   4   13.362500
2          0     [1,2)  30 -5.135667  1   39  15.673846
3          0     [2,3)  40 -6.994250  1   36  15.483056
4          0     [3,4)  27 -8.513333  1   21  15.055714
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my approach. It uses the fantastic `plyr` library by Hadley Wickham.

```
library(plyr)
Trades = read.csv("Trades.csv")

# define breaks to bin the data
breaks = c(0:9, 32)

# define profitable and ATRVE.cut variables
Trades = transform(Trades, 
    profitable  = ifelse(Trade.Profit.Loss.Perc >=0, 1, 0),
    ATRVE.cut = cut(Entry.ATRVE, breaks, right = FALSE)
)

# split data frame by ATRVE.cut and profitable and apply functions
Trades_Summary = ddply(Trades, .(ATRVE.cut, profitable), summarize,
    Num  = length(Trade.Profit.Loss.Perc),
    Mean = mean(Trade.Profit.Loss.Perc)
)

print(Trades_Summary)
```

This produces the output

```
  ATRVE.cut profitable Num       Mean
1     [0,1)          0   6  -5.383333
2     [1,2)          0   3 -13.883333
```

EDIT: To format the output as desired by the OP, here are a few additional lines

```
p0 = subset(Trades_Summary, profitable == 0)
p1 = subset(Trades_Summary, profitable == 1)
merge(p0, p1, by = 'ATRVE.cut')
```

This produces the output

```
    ATRVE.cut profitable.x Num.x  Mean.x     profitable.y
1     [0,1)            0     2 -1.305000            1
2     [1,2)            0    30 -5.135667            1
3     [2,3)            0    40 -6.994250            1
4     [3,4)            0    27 -8.513333            1
   Num.y   Mean.y
1     4 13.36250
2    39 15.67385
3    36 15.48306
4    21 15.05571
```

Comment: Thank you, that's much clearer. To summarise, add additional columns based on conditions and then pass those columns as variables to the ddply function for it to split by.
1. If I wanted to column bind a variable rather than row bind, how would I do this?
2. I also noted that the length and mean values are wrong; they seem to be using the wrong number of elements. When I can attach files, I will.

Comment: dput(Trades) = structure(list(Entry.ATRVE = c(0.487, 0.61, 0.663, 0.771, 0.816, 
1.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.4, 1.5), Trade.Profit.Loss.Perc = c(-4.76, -4.2, 
4, 10, -3.09, -8.14, 4, -4, 4, -4), profitable = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), ATRVE.cut = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("[0,1)", "[1,2)", "[2,3)", "[3,4)", 
"[4,5)", "[5,6)", "[6,7)", "[7,8)", "[8,9)", "[9,32)"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Entry.ATRVE", 
"Trade.Profit.Loss.Perc", "profitable", "ATRVE.cut"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: @Look Left. see my edited answer. it works fine. for each value of `profitable` and `ATRVE.cut` it calculates the number of trades and the mean value. if you can post what is the output you are looking for, i can compare against mine and debug further

Comment: @Ramnath I've updated my question to include to include an output based on your code.  I hope this describes what I mean by column binding. When I use larger data sets the numbers don't match my Excel reference sheet but I'll debug that later; it could be NA values.

Comment: @Look Left. your output is confusing. your data frame contains 10 trades of which 6 are losses (4 in [0, 1) and 2 in [1, 2)) and 4 are profits (3 in [0, 1) and 1 in [1, 2)). but your output shows that there are 9 trades ending in a loss and 7 ending in profits which seems inconsistent. can you clarify?

Comment: @Ramnath. My output was just an example of formatting. I would like to upload a larger input file and display a larger exact output to show all the workings but I can't.  Until I lose my 'newbie' tag i'm very limited which is frustrating to both. Editing the original question seems strange as it disturbs the conversation flow but that's what i'll need to do. Any other suggestions to get this data across?

Comment: @Look. check my latest edit to produce output in the format you desired

Comment: Thank you very much, that's another function in my memory arsenal.